# Transfer Value from drop down to a

Tags: if-statement, asp-classic

I need some help ...

I need the location drop down box to determine the appropriate inbox the form should be sent to.

ex if I choose Houston from the drop down box it will send it to the PayrollUSA email.

Im currently using a radio button to make the selection but i would like to automate with the drop down.

Im pretty new to this but im sure theres a if statement that can tie them together...

im using .asp for this.

```
                <input type="radio" name="payroll" value="PayrollUSA@mail.com" checked="checked">US Payroll
                <input type="radio" name="payroll" value="PayrollCAN@mail.com">CAN Payroll  
                <input type="radio" name="payroll" value="PayrollUK@mail.com">UK Payroll
                <input type="radio" name="payroll" value="PayrollHK@mail.com">HK Payroll
```

Drop down selection

```
           <SELECT SIZE="1" NAME="Business_Unit" style="width: 205px;" class="answers">
              <option selected >Select</option>
                <OPTION>Calgary</OPTION>
                <OPTION>Chicago</OPTION>
                <OPTION>Hong Kong</OPTION>
                <OPTION>Houston</OPTION>
                <OPTION>London</OPTION>
                <OPTION>Los Angeles</OPTION>
                <OPTION>Montreal</OPTION>
                <OPTION>New York</OPTION>
                <OPTION>New York Corporate</OPTION>
                <OPTION>Philadelphia</OPTION>
                <OPTION>San Francisco</OPTION>
                <OPTION>Toronto</OPTION>
                <OPTION>Toronto Corporate</OPTION>
                <OPTION>Vancouver</OPTION>
             </SELECT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the option value to be held then try this:

```
<SELECT SIZE="1" NAME="Business_Unit" style="width: 205px;" class="answers">
    <option value="">Select an Option</option>
    <option <% if Business_Unit= "PayrollCAN@mail.com" then %> selected <% End if %> value="PayrollCAN@mail.com">Calgary</option>
    <option <% if Business_Unit= "PayrollUSA@mail.com" then %> selected <% End if %> value="PayrollUSA@mail.com">Chicago</option>                       
</select>
```

etc. for each option and same value may be used for different option displays

Comment: @OP: I would also say that you'd get a better result by storing the the city names and linked email addresses in a database of some description.  That way you can expand your possibilities without having to continually recode your pages.

Comment: @allski i tweeked your solution and it worked!! 

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score -1):

I imaging this should just be html based. So your option menu should look like:

```
<SELECT SIZE="1" NAME="Business_Unit" style="width: 205px;" class="answers">
          <option value="-1">Select an Option</option>
            <OPTION value="PayrollCAN@mail.com">Calgary</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollUSA@mail.com">Chicago</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollHK@mail.com">Hong Kong</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollUSA@mail.com">Houston</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollUK@mail.com">London</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollUSA@mail.com">Los Angeles</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollCAN@mail.com">Montreal</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollUSA@mail.com">New York</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollUSA@mail.com">New York Corporate</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollUSA@mail.com">Philadelphia</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollUSA@mail.com">San Francisco</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollCAN@mail.com">Toronto</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollCAN@mail.com">Toronto Corporate</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PayrollCAN@mail.com">Vancouver</OPTION>
         </SELECT>
```

You can use the same value multiple times if needed

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need a way to also keep the value of the selected City.

Comment: Can you use the javascript onChange method for the select or does this need to be in asp?